# не срабатывает `final public function` или как ограничить вызов метода

Tags: php, mvc, объекты

Я пытаюсь создать кастомный конструктор query запросов на php используя PDO.
Столкнулся с проблемой: Мой класс позволяет повторно вызывать  некоторые методы. Скажем класс который создает экземпляр PDO объекта с подключением к базе можно вызвать по цепочке несколько раз.

```php
    final public function query($table) 
    {
        $this->sql = str_replace(':table', $table, $this->sql);
        try {
          $this->sql =  $this->db
              ->query($this->sql);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

В итоге

`debug(get_class_methods((new DataBase)->query('users')));`

```
array(27) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) "__construct"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "query"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "find"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "select"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "get"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "getArray"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "execute"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "fetch"
  [8]=>
  string(9) "bindParam"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "bindColumn"
  [10]=>
  string(9) "bindValue"
  [11]=>
  string(8) "rowCount"
  [12]=>
  string(11) "fetchColumn"
  [13]=>
  string(8) "fetchAll"
  [14]=>
  string(11) "fetchObject"
  [15]=>
  string(9) "errorCode"
  [16]=>
  string(9) "errorInfo"
  [17]=>
  string(12) "setAttribute"
  [18]=>
  string(12) "getAttribute"
  [19]=>
  string(11) "columnCount"
  [20]=>
  string(13) "getColumnMeta"
  [21]=>
  string(12) "setFetchMode"
  [22]=>
  string(10) "nextRowset"
  [23]=>
  string(11) "closeCursor"
  [24]=>
  string(15) "debugDumpParams"
  [25]=>
  string(8) "__wakeup"
  [26]=>
  string(7) "__sleep"
}
```

На сколько я понял [ключевое слово `final`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.final.php) должно ограничить этот вызов, но видимо я что-то не правильно понял.

Учитывая что пишу я это для себя - проблемы нет. Но если делать то хотелось бы сделать правильно.

Сейчас получается что `debug((new DataBase)->query('users')->query('news'))`

`Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\OSPanel\domains\circle\admin\application\lib\DataBase.php on line 20`

Comment: ключевое слово `final` не даёт переопределить метод в классе наследнике. Или запрещает наследование, если применяется к классу. Для того, чтобы метод нельзя было повторить дважды, нужно чтобы `query`  возвращал не `$this`, а новый объект, в котором нет метода `query`. Ферштейн?

Comment: Также советую вам не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками. Благо их очень много. Только если это не для самообразования.

Comment: @ArchDemon В первую очередь для саморазвития как раз и занимаюсь. На  счет готовых библиотек знаю, и пользуюсь ими.

Comment: final не ограничивает вызов функции единожды, оно ограничивает переопределение функции в наследуемых классах. Чтобы ограничить вызов - добавьте счетчик, который при вызове будет проверять сколько раз эта функция была вызвана.